# Red hat middleware Camel parse JDBC output

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, apache-camel, redhat

I am trying route data in Red Hat CodeReady Studio 12.16.0.GA from JDBC.
I successfuly read data from JDBC using jdbc:datasource.
My camelContext with route is this:

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="simple-route">
        <from id="_to2" uri="timer:timerName?delay=0&amp;period=0&amp;repeatCount=1"/>
        <setBody id="_setBody1">
            <constant>select * from cis_kraj</constant>
        </setBody>
        <to id="_to1" uri="jdbc:myDataSource"/>
        <split id="_split1" streaming="true">
            <simple resultType="java.lang.String" trim="false">${body}</simple>
            <log id="_log1" message="->> ${body}"/>
        </split>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

and output is this

```
15:39:44.085 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #4 - timer://timerName] INFO  simple-route - ->> [{id=1
15:39:44.086 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #4 - timer://timerName] INFO  simple-route - ->>  ext_id=null
15:39:44.086 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #4 - timer://timerName] INFO  simple-route - ->>  nazov=Bratislavský
15:39:44.086 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #4 - timer://timerName] INFO  simple-route - ->>  skratka=BL
15:39:44.087 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #4 - timer://timerName] INFO  simple-route - ->>  id_stat=SK}
15:39:44.087 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #4 - timer://timerName] INFO  simple-route - ->>  {id=2
15:39:44.087 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #4 - timer://timerName] INFO  simple-route - ->>  ext_id=null
15:39:44.087 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #4 - timer://timerName] INFO  simple-route - ->>  nazov=Trnavský
```

When I change resultType to java.util.Arrays it doesn't work.
How to change split to log only name from each row?

Comment: JDBC returns an ArrayList. I am not 100% sure since I have never tried this, but you could change the resultType to `java.util.List` and check.

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak JDBC doesn't return array lists anywhere in the JDBC API.

Comment: camel-jdbc does. https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jdbc-component.html#_result

Comment: Thank you for comments. java.util.List is the right way to return nazov row by row.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for comments.
java.util.List is the right way to return nazov row by row.

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="simple-route">
        <from id="_to2" uri="timer:timerName?delay=0&amp;period=0&amp;repeatCount=1"/>
        <setBody id="_setBody1">
            <constant>select * from cis_kraj</constant>
        </setBody>
        <to id="_to1" uri="jdbc:myDataSource"/>
        <split id="_split1" streaming="true">
            <simple resultType="java.util.List" trim="false">${body}</simple>
            <log id="_log1" message="->> ${body[nazov]}"/>
        </split>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```